# Why does AbstractCollection implement both Iterable and Collection?

Tags: java, collections, interface

`AbstractCollection` implements both the `Iterable` and `Collection` interfaces. However, `Collection` is a *subinterface* of `Iterable`. Would it not suffice just to have `AbstractCollection` implement `Collection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Javadocs for `AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) could be interpreted that `AbstractCollection` *directly* implements `Collection` and `Iterable`.

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> Iterable, Collection

However, [a quick look at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java) indicates that it only directly implements `Collection`.

> ```
> public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
> ```

Therefore, the Javadocs must be interpreted as saying that the class implements the given interfaces directly *or indirectly*.  As you've indicated, there would be no need for `AbstractCollection` to implement `Iterable` directly, because it already implements `Collection`.  The source code shows that it doesn't implement `Iterable` directly.  It does suffice for `AbstractCollection` to implement only `Collection` directly.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea that javadoc did that. I just assumed that was the way the source code was written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would suffice. But, explicitly listing both allows one to tell (by simple inspection) that `AbstractCollection` implements both `Iterable` and `Collection` (also, because it's `abstract` it doesn't necessarily implement either interface - but any concrete sub-class will).